# PHP4 Queue Server

Tags: php, queue, server

I've been looking at this PHP queue server : http://squirrelshaterobots.com/programming/php/building-a-queue-server-in-php-part-1-understanding-the-project/

This looks pretty good but the issue is I'm stuck on a very old defunct PHP4 based network drive to run my script.

What I'd like to do is queue commands, that the worker script will then action.  Most commands will be based on fsockopen and connect to other network devices, send them some information and the close the connection.  This will repeat, but I want to do them in the order they are sent to the 'queue'.

I had wondered about having a file to send the commands to and the worker read from the top of that file list.. but I'm not sure how I would do this and if I'll get issues with the file being open by the queue or worker at the same time.

Can anyone offer some advise how I may be able to do this on this older version of PHP4.

Thanks

Comment: The code in the article you linked (in parts 2 and 3 that is where the important bits are) doesn't have anything that may make it fail under PHP4. Give it a try and replace the `process()` body with your code to connect to the network resources.

Comment: Thanks Carlos - I'd read part 4 about the forking and that doesn't work on my PHP4 build.

Comment: I have just checked and both pcntl_* and posix_* did exist in PHP4, you may need to enable them (pcntl doesn't work in windows though, are you in windows?)

Comment: This is a really old box and I don't have access to add support for pcntl & posix. I'll see if I can do anything with the code..